# Use of “as” with a different verb

Tags: prepositions

I wonder how to use “as”? I saw the third sentence below in an article.

> 1. I found him as injured.

> 2. Couples shouldn't go to bed as angry at each other.

> 3. Although most regard him as authoritarian, no one questions him.

What is the difference between these sentences? I wonder why we can say “regard as authoritarian” but can’t say “find him as injured” or “go to bed as angry”? If I use “as” with different verbs in this way would it make the sentence meaningless?

Comment: Please edit your question to include just one question. People looking for the answer to your second question cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the third sentence is idiomatic and correct.  **as** is used with verbs of perception and judgement, to mean something like "I perceive the object in this way" or "I judge the object to be this way."  "Most regard him as authoritarian" means "most people think that he is authoritarian".

So you can see how "Couples shouldn't go to bed as angry at each other" doesn't make sense - who is doing the perceiving here?  This is just an imperative statement.

In "I found him as injured," *found* isn't really a verb that has to do with perception or judgement.  He was injured or he wasn't; this is not a matter of judgement.

Comment: Thanks. Should I use any preposition or conjunction in the second and first sentence? I mean is there ant full version of these sentence?

Comment: For the first sentence, you could say "I found him *to be* injured", although that is very "wordy" and formal.  For the second one, I don't think there is really any appropriate preposition or conjunction: the couple will "go to bed" and the way they do it is "angry", so "go to bed angry" is really the only correct way to phrase it.